# The type or namespace 'Feeds' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, rss, repeater, rss-reader

I am trying to fetch RSS feed from a website and display it using a repeater on my website. But I get an error message wherever I use 'Feeds' in my code below:

```
private void PopulateRssFeed()
{
    string RssFeedUrl = "http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533965/index.rss";
    List<Feeds> feeds = new List<Feeds>();
    try
    {
        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
        xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);
        var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
                     select new
                     {
                         title = x.Element("title").Value,
                         link = x.Element("link").Value,
                         pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
                         description = x.Element("description").Value
                     });
        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var i in items)
            {
                Feeds f = new Feeds
                {
                    Title = i.title,
                    Link = i.link,
                    PublishDate = i.pubDate,
                    Description = i.description
                };
                feeds.Add(f);
            }
        }
        rssRepeater.DataSource = feeds;
        rssRepeater.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I get the error on the below lines

```
  List<Feeds> feeds = new List<Feeds>();
  Feeds f = new Feeds;
```

Feeds class is as below:

```
   namespace MumbaiLyst
    {
      public class Feeds
      {
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Link { get; set; }
       public string PublishDate { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
      }
    }
```

and this is how the repeater looks like:

```
   <asp:Repeater ID = "rssRepeater" runat = "server">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3 style="color:#3E7CFF"><%#Eval("Title") %></h3>
        </td>
        <td width="200px">
            <%#Eval("PublishDate") %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <hr />
            <%#Eval("Description") %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right">
            <a href='<%#Eval("Link") %>' target="_blank">Read More...</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: where is your Feeds class...show it???

Comment: @Exception - Check the class mate.

Answer (score 0):

The code runs perfectly for me. I placed all code in a Default.aspx.cs file. The Feeds class is in the same file in the same namespace. There is no problem with the code itself.

Without knowing the structure of your project it is not possible to give an exact reason why your code can't see the Feeds class.